# Selecting dates of month based on existing rows

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have a table with the following schema:

```
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`bookingDate` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
```

I need to get all dates of the current month where there's less than 5 bookings. (meaning where less than 5 rows exist where bookingDate == date)

I tried iterating over every day of the month individually, but for performance reasons it really doesn't make sense to perform +/- 30 queries for every month.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly didn't work out?

Comment: Hint: You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses to count the bookings for each date and filter the results

Comment: GROUP BY does it all at once, while CTE is a fancy way to iterate.

Comment: @user1191247 - That _may_ be best done with a `LEFT JOIN` from a table that has all dates.  See an example in https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#sequence

Comment: @user1191247 - The similar question has the disadvantage of not using MariaDB.  Also, note that MariaDB has 2 types of "sequencing" -- an engine and a pseudo-table for building a sequence of numbers.  The latter can easily be +dynamically_ turned into a series of consecutive _dates_ for the OP's task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead you could just find all dates that *HAVE* 5 or more bookings and implement according logic on your client-side app.

```
SELECT bookingDate
FROM bookings
GROUP BY bookingDate
HAVING COUNT(bookingDate) > 4;
```

Comment: Isn't this "option 2" in my answer?

Comment: Why more than 4 in the condition?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this more efficiently, you can use a single query. Here's a step-by-step breakdown of the solution:

Generate all dates for the current month.
LEFT JOIN the generated dates with the booking table on the bookingDate.
Group by the date and count the bookings for each date.
Filter out the dates that have 5 or more bookings.
Here's how you can do it:

```
-- Step 1: Generate all dates for the current month
WITH RECURSIVE DateSequence AS (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') AS dateValue -- Start from the first day of the current month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM DateSequence
    WHERE DATE_ADD(dateValue, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) -- Up to the last day of the current month
)

-- Step 2, 3, and 4
SELECT ds.dateValue
FROM DateSequence ds
LEFT JOIN YourTableName t ON ds.dateValue = t.bookingDate
GROUP BY ds.dateValue
HAVING COUNT(t.id) < 5;
```

Replace YourTableName with the name of your booking table. The result of this query will give you all the dates of the current month where there are less than 5 bookings.

The advantage of this approach is that you get your result in one query, reducing the overhead of multiple individual queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of tackling this.

**Option 1** (not really an option)

```sql
SELECT bookingDate
FROM bookings
WHERE bookingDate BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-30'
GROUP BY bookingDate
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```

This will only return `bookingDate`s with 1, 2, 3 or 4 bookings, as it does not know about dates with zero bookings.

**Option 2**

You could invert the above query and iterate over the result in your client application, unsetting all dates that exist in the result:

```sql
SELECT bookingDate
FROM bookings
GROUP BY bookingDate
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

But, that just feels *clunky* to me.

**Option 3**

You could start with the full list of days you are interested in, generated using MariaDB's [Sequence Storage Engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/):

```sql
/* Full list of days in September 2023 based on first
 * of month and number of days in month */
SELECT '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL (seq - 1) DAY AS dt
FROM seq_1_to_30;

/* Full list of days in current month */
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY + INTERVAL (seq - 1) DAY AS dt
FROM seq_1_to_31
WHERE seq <= DAY(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE));
```

Obviously, there is no need for this step if you already have a calendar table with all dates, or a contiguous set to work with.

And then `LEFT JOIN` to your `bookings`:

```sql
SELECT s.dt, COUNT(b.id) AS num_bookings
FROM (
    SELECT '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL (seq - 1) DAY AS dt
    FROM seq_1_to_30
) s
LEFT JOIN bookings b
    ON s.dt = b.bookingDate
GROUP BY s.dt
HAVING num_bookings < 5;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qifBQKMw) to play with.

---

**Note:** Your current table is lacking an index on `bookingDate`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE bookings ADD INDEX idx_booking_date (bookingDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you:

-- Retrieve dates of the current month with less than 5 bookings

```
SELECT DISTINCT bookingDate
FROM bookings # your-table-name
WHERE MONTH(bookingDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(bookingDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY bookingDate
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```